# Compiling Linux kernel module against the wrong kernel headers, what happens?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was working on some scripts that we have to build a small-time Linux OS that we produce at work. I found a bug in the scripts. We were building a kernel module against the wrong set of kernel headers.

What makes this interesting is that the kernel module built fine, so the script simply copied it to the location under /lib/modules/ that corresponded with the kernel that we *intended* to build against, not the one we *actually* built against. The script then ran depmod.

In this scenario (which is obviously wrong), what should the expected behavior be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module which has been built with the wrong set of kernel headers can be loaded into the kernel, but its functionality is questionable (*Undefined Behaviour*).

It is possible that your module uses structures whose layout differs from the ones used by *intended* kernel.

If you are lucky and your module neither uses direct access (including access through macros and `static inline` functions) to the changed fields nor allocates memory for that structure (on the stack or on the heap), your module will operate as expected. Otherwise **something will go wrong**.

Comment: Thanks, this is along the lines of what I expected/experienced, but wanted to verify.